# Logout in spring controller

Tags: java, spring, jwt

I was wondering how I could revoke my JWT token from server. Why I need it because when client will logout from application then. It should kill exsiting token for client. But I was wondering how I could implement it. I searched from google there only explanation of how to authenticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more about your setup I'll have to use a few assumptions. In most cases access tokens (not just JWT) will have a time to live, i.e. a period during which they are valid and during which the service provider (your service) doesn't check for their validity again (for performance reasons). After the token has expired the service provider would normally use the refresh token provided by the identity provider (auth server) to get a new access token for that user - if still logged in.

So if the user logged out (and the identity provider knows of this) refreshing the access token would fail and thus you'd know the user has been logged out. Until then the service provider wouldn't attempt a refresh and wouldn't know the user logged out (elsewhere).

What to do? You might want to store the active access tokens and refresh tokens in your application (service provider) and if the user logs out you delete those associated with that user. The user would then be redirected to the identity provider.

If the user logs out elsewhere the identity provider would need to inform all service providers to delete certain access and refresh tokens.

Comment: I understand it that's why I should store all token in database. To know which still live which is already expired. But In fact how I could revoke existed token from server till it expired itself

Comment: @JahongirSabirov you normally need to tell the identity provider that the user has logged out and most of those provide an API to do so. For some more information have a look here: https://www.baeldung.com/logout-spring-security-oauth (if you're using something else it might still get you started/pointed into the right direction).